Sample size and coefficient of variation
I would like to know a relationship between sample size and coefficient of variation (CV). CV is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean. Could we say "smaller sample size results in larger CV, so that the relationship has negative correlation"?
Our situation: There are many small areas. Each area has its own sample. As a note, sample size for areas of urban regions is large, while of rural regions is small. Now, we have data following a Poisson distribution for areas. When we compute the CVs for all the areas respectively, we observe that the CVs for areas of rural regions with small sample size are large. We would like to investigate whether this is an effect of the sample size or not.
library(dplyr)
library(rsample)

cv <- function(x){return(sd(x)/mean(x))}
sim <- data.frame(id=1:100000, 
                variable=rpois(100000, 5),
                group10=sample(1:10,100000,replace=TRUE),
                group100=sample(1:100,100000,replace=TRUE),
                group1000=sample(1:1000,100000,replace=TRUE),
                group10000=sample(1:10000,100000,replace=TRUE)
                )
AA <- NULL
G <- c(10,100,1000,10000)
for(k in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:G[k]){

  if(k==1){
    A <- dplyr::filter(sim, group10==j)
  }else if(k==2){
    A <- dplyr::filter(sim, group100==j)
  }else if(k==3){
    A <- dplyr::filter(sim, group1000==j)
  }else if(k==4){
    A <- dplyr::filter(sim, group10000==j)
  }
  
  AA <- rbind(AA, c(G[k],
                    j,
                    nrow(A),
                    mean(A$variable),
                var(A$variable),
                    sd(A$variable),
                cv(A$variable)
                    )
              )
  }
}
AA <- as.data.frame(AA)
colnames(AA) <- c("Group","GroupN","N","Mean","Var","SD","CV")
head(AA)
tail(AA)

AA10 <- AA %>% filter(Group==10)
AA100 <- AA %>% filter(Group==100)
AA1000 <- AA %>% filter(Group==1000)
AA10000 <- AA %>% filter(Group==10000)

(cv(sim$variable))

par(mfrow = c(1, 4))
plot(AA10$N,AA10$CV, ylim=c(0,1.2), ylab="CV",xlab="Sample Size",
     main="10-groups")
abline(h=cv(sim$variable),col="red")
plot(AA100$N,AA100$CV, ylim=c(0,1.2), ylab="CV",xlab="Sample Size",
 main="100-groups")
abline(h=cv(sim$variable),col="red")
plot(AA1000$N,AA1000$CV, ylim=c(0,1.2), ylab="CV",xlab="Sample Size",
     main="1,000-groups")
abline(h=cv(sim$variable),col="red")
plot(AA10000$N,AA10000$CV, ylim=c(0,1.2), ylab="CV",xlab="Sample Size",
 main="10,000-groups")
abline(h=cv(sim$variable),col="red")
dev.off()



Quick answer: No. The CV is a dimensionless metric enabling comparisons of the variability of data with differing scales -- sample size is not a consideration. For example, systolic and diastolic metrics of blood pressure differ in their means and standard deviations. CVs of each allow one to determine which metric has more variability.

@user78229 That looks like an answer to me!

This doesn't look like a study of variation with sample size, because you are sampling from different distributions altogether.  Could you explain what you think your code is doing?

This question doesn't make any sense, and can't be answered helpfully, without details. What distribution are you assuming for the data?  What is your code (supposed to be) doing? It seems to simulate four sample sizes, but your graphs show many more sample sizes.  In a later comment, you discuss your finding that CV is related to n, but I don't see that in your graphs. Many more details are needed.

It is not easy to follow what your code is doing. That makes it that the focus of your question is unclear. It leads to different answers that do not deal with your point that the CV is dependent on sample size and do not respond to the construction in your code.

You might compute the exact mean CV for samples of particular size, but how do you deal with the cases where the sample has mean zero? Whatever value you fill in (between zero or one), based on some quick simulations, it seems that the average CV for these samples increases when you increases the sample size.

@SextusEmpiricus Oh, that is my facing problem. Our situation is as follow. There are many small areas. Each area has its own sample. As a note, sample size for areas of urban regions is large, while of rural regions is small. Now, we have data following a Poisson distribution for areas. When we compute the CVs for all the areas respectively, we observe that the CVs for areas of rural regions with small sample size are large. We would like to investigate whether this is an effect of the sample size or not.

It appears the question you have asked has little to do with your actual problem.  Indeed, one is led to wonder about the point of computing CVs in the first place: what do you really need to know?

On the substantive side, why do you think a Poisson distribution makes sense for areas? Are you counting pixels?  From a another point of view, variance = mean is characteristic of the Poisson, so it's not obvious to me that SD / mean is a good measure to work with.

@Tky in the example from your question the sample size had no effect on the distribution that you sample from. In your problem about urban (large sample) versus rural (small sample) there might be a relationship with sample size because the samples distributions themselves depend on the sample size.

@SextusEmpiricus I appreciate your comments to make my interest clear. I would like to investigate your comments: "In your problem about urban (large sample) versus rural (small sample) there might be a relationship with sample size because the samples distributions themselves depend on the sample size." To investigate the effect of sample size, how should we set the sampling? Currently, we assumed the same distribution (Poisson) for all small areas. It may be meaningless for investigating our problem.

@Tky it is difficult to say without knowing what variable is being investigated. Family size? But that's not Poisson distributed is it? I think that it might be good to get a better idea first about a theoretically supported research question. Start with why it is that you believe sample size matters, then based on that device a plan to support it with statistics.

@SextusEmpiricus The variable is the number of steps. Research question is to investigate a disparity of the number of steps. Following Althoff et al. (2017, Nature) which showed the difference in some countries, we are studying it at small area-level in our country. When we compared CVs for checking the disparity, we observed that CVs for areas of rural regions with small sample size are large. Therefore, we would like to know the effect of sample size for CVs.
https://doi.org/10.1038/nature23018

Regarding on distribution, the distribution for each area is actually different as Althoff et al. (2017, see Fig. 1). Although we assumed Poisson distribution in our simulation, it is just assumption, not has a theoritical background.

I don't think that using a Poisson distribution is so great. With a more precise underlying distribution you could make estimates of the error in the CV, and see whether sample size of the area has an influence on the distribution. A simple way would be to use some bootstrapping method. Then you can see whether there is a trend that areas with small sample size have a different distribution with higher CV or whether a sampling variation is also a likely explanation.

If you have a very strong effect, then you could make a scatter plot of mean and standard deviation for the different areas (possibly with a color coding for the sample size) and see if there are relationships. What you see in the figure 1 of the article is that CV relates to the mean. Saudi Arabia with low mean steps has a larger CV and Japan with high mean steps has a smaller CV. You might argue that this is because there is some upper limit (there seem to be few people with more than 15000 steps). If the mean is higher, then the upper limit gets closer to the mean and that reduces the CV.

This question and its answers (mine too!) don't hang together well. The first answers were directed at the original question, short enough to be quoted in its entirety: I would like to know a relationship between sample size and coefficient of variation (CV). CV is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean. Could we say "larger sample size results in smaller CV, so that the relationship has negative correlation"? Now the question is morphing untidily to one about (a) some data, off-stage (b) some simulation results, which aren't obviously close to each other.

I have an awkward meta-question, simple to ask but possibly hard to tackle. Why is the coefficient of variation a natural measure for your empirical project? It makes most sense wherever positive measured variables are such that SD is roughly proportional to mean, which is precisely why their ratio is calculated.

The sample size $n$ does impart an upper limit on observable coefficient of variation. These limits have been noticed, hence the results below, but will not often bite in practice. In my view, sampling variation is typically a bigger deal.
Katsnelson and Kotz (1957) proved that so long as all data are zero or positive, then the coefficient of variation cannot exceed $\sqrt{n−1}$, a result mentioned earlier by Longley (1952).
Cramér (1946, 357) proved a less sharp result, and Kirby (1974) proved a less general result.
Cramér, H. 1946. Mathematical Methods of Statistics. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press.
Katsnelson, J., and S. Kotz. 1957. On the upper limits of some measures of variability. Archiv für Meteorologie, Geophysik und Bioklimatologie, Series B 8: 103–107.
Kirby, W. 1974. Algebraic boundedness of sample statistics. Water Resources Research 10: 220–222.
Longley, R. W. 1952. Measures of the variability of precipitation. Monthly Weather Review 80: 111–117.
See https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1001000311 for discussion of limits that arise similarly on sample skewness and kurtosis.

@dave Per your suggestion.
Quick answer: No. The CV is a dimensionless metric enabling comparisons of the variability of data with differing scales -- sample size is not a consideration. For example, systolic and diastolic metrics of blood pressure differ in their means and standard deviations. CVs of each allow one to determine which metric has more variability.

But, both mean and standard deviation include sample size to calculate them.

@Tky the calculations are scaled by the sample size, but the parameters are population characteristics (they are constant). Smaller samples have lower precision for estimating these parameters, which is what leads to more extreme observed CVs.

@PBulls I really appreciate your comments. Yes, I confirmed the "Smaller samples have lower precision for estimating these parameters" by the R codes. I would like Just to make sure what you mean "extreme observed CVs". Do you mean only "over"-estimate for CVs?

@Tky No, they are more extreme in both directions (larger & smaller; over- and underestimations of the true value). You can clearly see this in your plots as well -- the small sample sizes can also result in much smaller observed CVs.

@PBulls Sampling variation is the main issue and so turning your comments into an answer would be most welcome.


Could we say "smaller sample size results in larger CV, so that the relationship has negative correlation"?

Your graphs show very similar coefficients of variation around $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} \approx 44.7\%$. A difference is that a sample does not have always this exact coefficient of variation and for smaller sample sizes the variation in the CV is larger.

By the way, your code is very verbose, indirect and difficult to follow.
It would have been easier to just sample directly from the Poisson  distribution with different sample sizes. E.g

set.seed(1)
n = 1:10000
cv = rep(NA, length(n))

for (ni in n) {
    x = rpois(ni,5)
    cv[ni] = sd(x)/mean(x)
}

plot(n,cv,pch=20)
lines(c(1,10000),c(1,1)*1/sqrt(5), col = 2)

